# How to generate/write an ID (alpha-numeric) while adding a new contact in XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xslt

Is it possible to generate a alpha-numeric ID during the creation of new contact in the xml file. 
I used XSLT function `<xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>` to generate a unique ID in my xml file in the beginning for serializing so i used the above to generate ID.

I can add a new record in xml file using JavaScript DOM in XUL.

```
function create()
{

var src = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\
<CONTACT>\
    <Customer-ID>"+document.getElementById("Customer-ID").value+"</Customer-ID>\
    <FirstName>"+document.getElementById("FirstName").value+"</FirstName>\
    <LastName>"+document.getElementById("LastName").value+"</LastName>\
    <email>"+document.getElementById("email").value+"</email>\
    <address>"+document.getElementById("address").value+"</address>\
    <state>"+document.getElementById("state").value+"</state>\
    <country>"+document.getElementById("country").value+"</country>\
</CONTACT>";

print(src);

var node = srcToNode(src);

    if (objXMLDoc.childNodes && objXMLDoc.childNodes.length) {

        for (var i = 0; i < objXMLDoc.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    if (objXMLDoc.childNodes.item(i).childNodes && objXMLDoc.childNodes.item(i).childNodes.length) {
         var x = objXMLDoc.childNodes.item(i).childNodes.length;
        var lastNode = objXMLDoc.childNodes.item(i).childNodes.item(x-2);

        }

      }

objXMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("CONTACT");//objXMLDoc.childNodes.item(0).lastChild;

objXMLDoc.appendChild(node); 
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var prettyString = serializer.serializeToString(objXMLDoc);
saveFile(prettyString, "C:\\contact.xml");
 }
}
```

The above code works perfectly to create a new record in my xml file. 
How can i generate a unique ID during the creation of new contact in my XML file? rather than typing the ID manually in the textbox ?

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONTACTS>

<CONTACT>
<Customer-ID>N65539</Customer-ID>
<FirstName>Ben</FirstName>
<LastName>Foden</LastName>
<email></email>
<address></address>
<state>AZ</state>
<country>US</country>
</CONTACT>

<CONTACT>
<Customer-ID>N65539</Customer-ID>
<FirstName>Nimal</FirstName>
<LastName>Anup</LastName>
<email>nimal.anup@gmail.com</email>
<address></address>
<state>TN</state>
<country>IN</country>
</CONTACT>


<CONTACTS>
```

Comment: you did not show the XSLT. Where did `generate-id()` fail? What's the question?

Comment: In my case, when I append a new contact to my XML file through XUL, I want to generate a unique ID for the new contact for the Customer-ID field in my XML file.I don't want to get the value of my textbox value to do the ID manually. How can i generate a unique ID using XSLT? only for the customer-id.  Is it possible to load the XSLT file in XML or is the any other way to generate a unique ID? Thanks.

Comment: Didn't you already use `generate-id(.)`? That's the XSLT way.

Comment: You are right. How can I use my XSLT file in my XML File to generate the ID? When I create a new contact how can i implement this function to generate the ID in the XML file? Thanks

Comment: Where's in the question the XSLT code? and how you think to get the XSLT file be executed?

Comment: Ups, so we can't execute the XSLT file! Then how can i generate the Unique ID? Do i have to run my XSLT file separately after I saved the new contact in my xml file in xul using JavaScript? Please explain to me the easy of doing it! Thank you.

Comment: Is it feasible for you? 1. save the new contact in the xml file using js, 2. then transform the XML file by your XSLT, always using js (you know there are js libraries that can work as XSLT processors).

Comment: If you are using XSLT just to generate the unique identifier, why not simply using javascript to do that?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how can I do that using JavaScript? I have no problem in saving the XML. Please give me some instruction to transform the XML file using XSLT, in js (I don't know how to use js libraries that can work as XSLT processors). Please explain to me. I thank you very much.

Comment: Please first make sure that some simple javascript trick is not enough for you as [this](http://forumsblogswikis.com/2008/05/26/how-to-generate-a-unique-id-in-javascript/).

Comment: Ok. then.... Please give me some more information.

Comment: I mean, if you google a bit, you'll find a lot of ways to generate a unique id using js. What's the problem?

Comment: Ok. Is there any way to generate unique ID in XML file? Sorry to bother you too much.

Comment: Sorry, do you want a pure XSLT answer?

Comment: If possible... I'm trying to follow this link to use the XSLT processor in XUL.JavaScript XSLT Support in Firefox <http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-ffox3/index.html> Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT copies the input XML as is and populate all `Customer-ID` element with a unique id:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Customer-ID">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl.value-of select="generate-id()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks. I'm using the following function //Create an XSLT processor instance
var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
//Create an empty XML document for the XSLT transform
var transform = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
//Load the XSLT
transform.onload = loadTransform;
transform.load("file://C:/idgenerator.xslt"); Where I couldn't load the file. Any idea..

Comment: Why you are creating an empty document? Didn't you want apply the transform to the saved one?

Comment: I'm following this link <http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-ffox3/index.html> to process my XML file using XSLT processor in Firefox/XUL.

Comment: Listing 6 should be your final answer: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-ffox3/index.html#listing6

Comment: You'r right. For some reason I couldn't load the file. probably a directory problem. Now i have an idea to proceed further. Thank you very much for your support and help :). You always nice to people. Thank you once again.